# jquery fileupload plugin issues in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having an issue with the `jquery.filedrop.js` plugin.

It does work in the VS2012 version of this project, so I'm not sure exactly why is broke in my new VS2015 version of this project.

The application was originally developed in Asp.Net MVC 5 in VS2012. I then ported it over to VS2015 with no issues, and proceeded with further development.

The exception occurs in `jquery.filedrop.js` plugin when I drag/drop the cvs file on the drop area (also see screen shot below):

`xhr.sendAsBinary() exception`

[image: xhr.sendAsBinary() exception]

In `Upload.cshtml`, I have this js and html code :

```js
$(".dropzone").filedrop({
 url: "@Url.Action("_UploadMultiple", "Portfolio")",
 paramname: "files",
 maxFiles: 10,
 maxfilesize: 10, // max file size in MB
 allowedfiletypes: [], // ["text/plain", "text/csv", "application/csv", "text/xml", "application/xml"] // Filetypes allowed by Content-Type, empty array means no restrictions
 allowedfileextensions: [".csv", ".xml"],
 dragOver: function () {
  $(".dropzone").css("background", "#eee");
 },
 dragLeave: function () {
  $(".dropzone").css("background", "#fff");
 },
 drop: function () {
  $(".dropzone").css("background", "#eee");
  // Add spinner
  $(".dropzone > p").html("<i class='fa fa-2x fa-refresh fa-spin'></i><br /><strong>Processing</strong>");
  
 },
 afterAll: function () {
  Alert.windowOk("Completed", "All files were processed. Please check the output for details.", "success",
   function () {
    $(".dropzone").css("background", "#fff");
    // Remove spinner
    $(".dropzone > p").html("<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-up'></i><br /><strong>Drop CSV or XML files here to upload</strong>");
   }
  );
 },
 uploadFinished: function (i, file, response, time) {
  UP.updateResults(response);
 },
 error: function (err, file) {
  switch (err) {
   default:
    break;
  }
  $(".dropzone").css("background", "#fff");
  // Remove spinner
  $(".dropzone > p").html("<i class='fa fa-2x fa-arrow-up'></i><br /><strong>Drop CSV or XML files here to upload</strong>");
 }
});
```

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
    ViewBag.Breadcrumb = "Upload";
}

@section styles {
  /* styles are here...*/
}

<form id="upload-form" action="@Url.Action("_Upload", "Portfolio")" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-md-2 dropzone" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <p class="text-center" style="margin-top:10px;">
   <i class="fa fa-2x fa-arrow-up"></i>
   <br />
   <strong>Drop CSV or XML files here to upload</strong>
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
</form>

@section scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.filedrop.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My jquery version is: `jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2`, which is the same as the original project with working filedrop version.

jquery.filedrop.js is `Version:  0.1.0` downloaded from https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop

In this screen shot, I'm showing what it looks like once the exception occurs and the processing spinner remains animated.

[image]

I'm wondering if I have a jquery conflict somewhere, and if someone could provide some guidance how to resolve this exception.

thank you,
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced the conflict to `pace.js`, used by the `inspinia.js` design template (I got the inspinia template from wrapbootstrap.com).

Commenting out `pace.min.js` in `BundleConfig.cs` removed the conflict.

Now to figure out how they pace.js and fileupload can live side-by-side...

```js
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/plugins").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js",
                      //"~/Scripts/plugins/pace/pace.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/plugins/inspinia/inspinia.js",
                      "~/Scripts/plugins/inspinia/skin.config.min.js"));
```

Have a look at the jquery.filedrop.js in Chrome debug window. You can see the `pace.min` reference as I hover over the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

[image]